# Find all complex $z$ such that $z=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{\frac{2\pi ikz}{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-sum

Here is what I tried:
The inner sum is a geometric series so $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{\frac{2\pi ikz}{n}} =\frac{e^{c}\left(e^{nc}-1\right)}{e^{c}-1}$$ where $c=\frac{2\pi iz}{n}$ and $nc=2\pi i z$. So the sum becomes $$z=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{\frac{2\pi ikz}{n}} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{e^{c}\left(e^{nc}-1\right)}{e^{c}-1}$$ 
$$\frac{z}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{e^{c}}{e^{c}-1}$$
But as $n$ approaches infinity $c$ approaches $0$ and $ \left|\frac{e^{c}}{e^{c}-1}\right|\ $ approaches infinity and the series diverges for all $z$ with $\left|z\right|\ $finite. What did I miss?

Comment: Hint: What if $e^{2\pi i z} = 1$?

Comment: Keep in mind it may be false for all complex $z$ too, and we should expect a contradiction in that case.